# Hibernate.cfg.xml parsing error

Tags: hibernate, hibernate.cfg.xml

<

```
!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

I have this in my hibernate.cfg.xml file. I have the jars downloaded (from http://www.javatpoint.com/src/hb/hibernatejar.zip) in WEB-INF folder in eclipse workspace. Still it says hibernate.sourceforge.net is unreachable. I replaced it with www.hibernate.org/dtd and that is also giving same error. Please help me fix this.

Same issue in mapping file as well.

Error after adding classpath in DOCTYPE:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at StoreData.main(StoreData.java:12)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: unknown protocol: classpath Nested exception: unknown protocol: classpath
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Are your libraries present in your application classpath?

Comment: i have added the jars in WEB-INF/lib folder. Apart from that, I added them in java build path also.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DOCTYPE` definition refers to a `DTD` that is on `hibernate.sourceforge.net`. Now that DTD exists (I can browse it via Firefox) but your application cannot access it. The purpose of the doctype element is to link to a DTD.

Try using below

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

Comment: I tried this also. This would mean it will refer from the DTD present in local. But the DTD is present only inside hibernate3.jar in my workspace. How do I point to the DTD inside jar?

Comment: @naveenbharadwaj which version of hibernate

Comment: I'm not sure. I downloaded the jars from a site. These are the set of jars I have in my workspace.
antlr-2.7.6.jar
asm-attrs.jar
asm.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.jar
cglib-2.1.3.jar
commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-1.2.3.jar
ejb3-persistence.jar
hibernate-annotations.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
hibernate-validator.jar
hibernate3.jar
jdbc2_0-stdext.jar
jta.jar
log4j-1.2.11.jar
ojdbc14.jar
xerces-2.6.2.jar

Comment: I extracted DTD's to a path and referred that in classpath. Now it is giving this error.
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: unknown protocol: classpath Nested exception: unknown protocol: classpath
 at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
 ... 2 more

Answer (score 0):

Following should be your complete DTD in **hibernate.cfg.xml** file

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Also do not forget following at the start in the file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

Comment: Can you post full contents of **hibernate.cfg.xml**?

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

    <mapping resource="lang.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Comment: Properties are removed from above comment.

Comment: Try following <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration> 
<session-factory> 
<mapping resource="lang.hbm.xml"/> 
</session-factory> 
</hibernate-configuration>

Comment: here's truncated url "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" from above string

Comment: Tried this also. Didnt work. I placed DTD files in local as mentioned in other answer. But I'm getting this error:
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: unknown protocol: classpath Nested exception: unknown protocol: classpath

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
 at StoreData.main(StoreData.java:12)

Comment: Please edit your question and post complete stack trace.

Comment: Note that your mapping files will have different Dtds. And also cross-check your properties in **hibernate.cfg.xml** there could be a problem over there.

Comment: That is taken care. I have both DTD's placed in classpath.

Comment: And also cross-check your properties in hibernate.cfg.xml there could be a problem over there.

Comment: It is giving error before parsing properties (in classpath itself). And I have checked proprties also.

Comment: Now you need to post complete application code for us to help you.